# Clear memory used by UIImage -- UIImageView.image = nil doesn't do it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimage, memory-management

I have created an `UIScrollView` that contains photos, like in the Photos app.

Photos are downloaded. Images are set through:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:downloadedImageData];
```

To save memory, when the user goes far from a photo, I set

```
imageView.image = nil;
```

This doesn't clear the memory, though. "Memory Leaks" from Instruments doesn't show any memory leaks.

Can anyone recommend me how to optimize the memory used by images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UIImage imageWithData:] is autoreleased object, so it will be freed somewhere in run loop. To release it for sure, use alloc/init constructor.